# How to ignore output variables in matlab?

Tags: matlab

```
[dummy index] = sort(A);
```

I want to ignore the first output of sort function and just keep the indices. When I use the above I get a warning in the matlab editor that:

> The value assigned to dummy is appears to be unused.

and it suggest to use ~ instead. When I use ~.

```
[~ index] = sort(A);
```

I got the following error:

> use ~ to ignore a value is not permitted in this context.

Anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: I'm confused. There is no use of ~ in your example that you say fails.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to add a comma and separate the output arguments to get ~ to work.

The following works

```
[dummy index] = sort(A);
[dummy, index] = sort(A);
[~, index] = sort(A);
```

but

```
[~ index] = sort(A);
```

fails.

Answer (score 0):

It does work, though your question does not even show you using a ~ where you say you get an error.

```
A = rand(1,5);
[~,ind] = sort(A);

ind
ind =
     3     5     1     2     4
```